# Pagination links not working in codeginiter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My Controller:-

```
function all_leads($offset = 0) {
    $where = '';
    $search['search_status'] = FALSE;
    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $user_id = $this->extra_functions->get_user_id($username);
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $user_type = $this->extra_functions->get_user_type($user_id);
    if ($this->input->get('search')) {
       $serach_string = $this->input->server('QUERY_STRING');
       $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
       $config['suffix'] = '?' . $serach_string;
       $search_data = $this->input->get();
       $where = $this->lead_model->lead_search_coundtiotn($search_data);
       if ($where != NULL) {
          $where = $where;
       } else {
          $where = '';
       }
       $main_data['search'] = TRUE;
       $main_data['search_data'] = $search_data;
    }
    $num_rows = $this->lead_model->count_leads($user_id, $user_type, $where);
    $config['base_url'] = base_url('lead/all_leads');
    $config['total_rows'] = $num_rows;
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['prev_link'] = '&laquo;';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['num_links'] = 5;
    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = '&raquo;';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $main_data['all_leads'] = $this->lead_model->view_leads_sec($config['per_page'], $offset, $search, $user_id, $user_type, $where);    
    $main_data['totalRecords']=$num_rows;
    $this->load->view('crm/leads/all_leads', $main_data);          
}
```

Comment: It does not show any error just pagination links not working properly.It skips some records when i m trying to search anything.Search working properly just pagination linkc not working fine...

Comment: did u set session and offset value should be change according to u r url_segment

Answer (score 0):

```
        $searchterm =$this->search_resource_model->searchterm_handler($this->input->post('keywords'));

                    //if serachterm is presnt
                             if($searchterm)
                             {
                            //pagenation code
          $offset = ($this->uri->segment(3) != '' ? $this->uri->segment(3): 0);
        $config['total_rows']=$this->search_resource_model->total_count($searchterm);
                            $config['per_page']= 5;
                            $config['first_url'] = '1';
                            $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';

                            $config['first_link'] = 'First';
                            $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
                            $config['base_url']= base_url().'search/search_by_keywords/'; 
                    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;  
     $data["reso_list"] = $this->search_resource_model->serch_with_kw($config["per_page"], $offset,$searchterm); 


                        //total count to display on view page
                        $data["total_count"]=$config['total_rows']; 

                        //initialize config variable
                        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
                        //create link for pagination
                        $data['paginglinks'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
                             }



//where in searchterm_handler i am setting session
public function searchterm_handler($searchterm)
{
    if($searchterm)
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata('searchterm', $searchterm);
        return $searchterm;
    }
    elseif($this->session->userdata('searchterm'))
    {
        $searchterm = $this->session->userdata('searchterm');
        return $searchterm;
    }
    else
    {
        $searchterm ="";

        return $searchterm;
    }
}
```

Comment: please set proper offset value.  i think u r using $this->uri->segment(3) its depend on u r url. i am using this because it is perfect for my url parameter. please tell me your url i will let you know what is u r offset value

Comment: I have tried segment value 4, 5 But still not working. Here is my URL :- http://192.168.1.109/emr/lead/all_leads/2?createdatefrom=2016-05-01&createdateto=2016-06-30&leadname=&service_s=&leadowner=&city_s=&mobile_num=&followup_date_from=&followup_date_to=&lead_src=&lead_status=&search=search

Answer (score -1):

Use **autoload** for library in config folder

exp:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','encrypt','pagination');
```

This is my pagination style , may be it is useful to you.

My controller:

```
public function album($id){
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $encpt = $this->encrypt->encode('howmuch?');
        # fetch records from database 
        //$this->data['posts'] = $this->Punjabi_Model->fetch_top_album($id);
        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "punjabi_music/album/".$id.'/';
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->Punjabi_Model->total_record($id);
        $config["per_page"] = 20;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 4;

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
        $this->data['posts'] = $this->Punjabi_Model->fetch_top_album($id,$config["per_page"], $page);
        $this->data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();


        $this->middle ='other/punjabi_music/album';
        $this->layout();

    }
```

Comment: @ChrisF This user is spammer, spamming the `phpcomment` stuff. Why did you edit this? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38076469

Comment: @PraveenKumar - this is at least an attempt at an answer. It includes code and instructions for it's use. Once the link was removed there was no issue.